# Is it possible to have multiple stacks of Screens in Blackberry?

Tags: blackberry

I am trying to implement a tab-style navigation system in my app (similar to the iOS UITabBarController). The functionality I am trying to create is that each tab holds it's own stack of screens, so that if one switches tabs the user changes to a different stack and can navigate back and forth independently of the other tabs, all the while showing a single tab bar at the top or bottom of the screen.

I have seen this functionality in apps such as Dropbox, but I am not sure if its possible to have multiple stacks or the behaviour is simply clever management of a single stack.

Any thoughts would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is only one stack of screens and RIM OS does not support multiple screen stacks.

And you should follow some rules to work with this single stack. For instance, to show previous screen, you need to pop (close) topmost one.

If you do not pop screens, but create more and more new ones, without closing old screens, then you will get OutOfMemoryException.

You will need to redesign your app, use custom Manager class instances and compose your own interface to implement the way of appearance you need.

EDIT: You can have as many in-memory lists of screen objects as you wish, or until they fit to the device memory. But RIM OS allows only one stack of *visible screens*.

Comment: You could of course maintain your own stacks of screens and just keep the current screen in the OS stack, to achieve the navigation you are aiming for. There is no need to be limited to the single stack that the OS naturally maintains.

Comment: @paulkayuk, what SDK do you mean? RIM OS SDK does not allow more than one stack of screens.

Comment: @Rafael Osipov, The RIM OS SDK maintains its own single stack of screens, as I agreed above, but there is absolutely nothing stopping you from defining your own stacks of screen objects, or any other stack for that matter, and managing the stacks yourself.

Comment: @paulkayuk, your suggestion is very useful for managing large application.

Comment: @paulkayuk, yes, you can define several stacks (lists) of screens. But you have to deal with this one (visible) stack of screens that is allowed by RIM OS. Your screen objects in your stacks will be invisible, until you set a screen to the top of RIM OS screen stack.

Comment: @Rafael, as I indicated in my first comment